# Почему не работает статический импорт?

Tags: java, импорт, static

Перешел к изучению статического импорта в Java. Создал класс A в котором есть статический метод B выводящий на консоль строку "Hi!". После этого создал класс Prog278 в который пытаюсь импортировать статический метод B но компилятор выдает ошибки указанные ниже. Подскажите как все таки импортировать данный статический метод в мою программу?

Класс со статическим методом

```
class A {
public static void B () {
    System.out.println ("Hi!");
}}
```

Класс в который импортируется статический метод

```
import static A.B;
class Prog278 {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    B();
}}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно спецификации языка, в объявлении импорта должно использоваться **полное** (англ. `qualified`) имя класса, то есть имя класса с указанием имени пакета. См. [спецификацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1):

> The name must be qualified (§6.5.5.2), or a compile-time error occurs.

Пакет по умолчанию  (англ. `default package`) (то есть пакет, к которому относятся классы, в которых не указано имя пакета), не имеет имени. Следовательно, классы, в которых не указано имя пакета, не могут иметь полного имени, поэтому их импортировать невозможно.

Поместите ваши классы в какую-нибудь директорию внутри вашей директории с исходниками, и добавьте в них объявление пакета с именем этой директории, что-то типа такого:

```
package mypackage;

class A {
  public static void B () {
    System.out.println ("Hi!");
  }
}
```

---

```
package mypackage;

import static mypackage.A.B;

public class C {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B();
  }
}
```

и всё заработает.

И кстати, не называйте методы (а также переменные и параметры методов) именами, начинающимися с большой буквы. Есть определенные соглашения, и несоблюдение их путает (и, следовательно, раздражает) читателей вашего кода. Погуглите "java naming conventions".

Comment: Строго говоря, достаточно поместить в именованный пакет только импортируемый класс, не обязательно оба.

Comment: Спасибо! Изучаю Java по книге Шилдта и подобной информации там не встречал

Comment: Ну в одной книжке трудно все нюансы отразить, тем более, чтобы понятным языком было написано. Все нюансы есть в спецификации, но ее читать трудно -- поэтому книжки и пишут. Ну и конкретно с этим нюансом мало кто сталкивался, поскольку обычно у всех все классы в пакетах и нет повода задуматься об особенностях, связанных c default package.

Comment: Сколько пользуюсь Java, никогда не делал статический импорт. Это точно нужная черта языка?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это очень странно. Я активно использую его почти всегда и считаю что да, конечно нужная. Но вопрос (и ответ) касается не только  статического, а любого вообще импорта.